# Orthogonalization methods other than Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Is there any other orthogonalization methods available other than Gram-Schmidt procedure ? Are all of them guranteed to produce the same span as the original linearly independent vectors produce.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonalization

Comment: This might be a good question for Computational Science Stack Exchange (check their FAQ first to make sure). I think the G-S method is not that good in practice and is not what people actually use on real problems.  There are lots of experts at Computational Science Stack Exchange who may know the state-of-the-art.

Answer (score 2):

You could try "Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra" by Carl D. Meyer (sections 5.5 - 5.7, there are 1) Gram–Schmidt, 2) Householder transformation, 3) Givens rotation + examples).